# No auth function available for given request

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm a newbie to access with DropBox's Api (See: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oauth2-methods). Now there's a problem rocking me——

1) I get an access_token successfully.
2) I wanna see the user's detailled info by directly calling "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/account/info". However the result is:

```
{"error_description": "No auth function available for given request", "error": "invalid_request"}
```

It seems that I should give the address something to make sure that I'm already authenticated. But how? I didn't see anything in Documents……? Any where?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The API uses OAuth 2, so you'll want to attach an "`Authorization`" header with the value "`Bearer ACCESSTOKEN`", where ACCESSTOKEN is the access token you obtained through the OAuth process.

Comment: in stackoverflow question is not one time people come and get help.please explain it further

Comment: What part do you need help understanding?

Comment: how to attrach authorization header with value bearer accesstoken 
example please

Comment: How you attach a header depends on what library you're using. If you have a question of the form "How do you add a header to an HTTP request using <library> in <language>?" please go ahead and open a new question.