# Error while getting Dropbox access token of user

Tags: react-native, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am currently trying to add a Dropbox file upload system in my `react-native` application. I have created an app in Dropbox console with App Folder access. When the user goes to my redirect URL, then I'm fetching the access token with the help of the Authorization code received from the login.

```
 await fetch(
      `https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token?code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=${appKey}&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/`,
      requestOptions,
    )
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

Here is my code for the same. But this gives me an error

```
{"error_description": "No auth function available for given request", "error": "invalid_request"}
```

Anyone ever faced this error or any idea about the reason for the same?

Question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028728/no-auth-function-available-for-given-request) but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is indicating that the request didn't supply the necessary parameters for this call.

If you are using the non-PKCE code flow, that's because you aren't supplying the `client_secret` parameter.

If you are using the PKCE flow, that's because you aren't supplying the `code_verifier` parameter.

You can find [the documentation for the Dropbox /oauth2/token endpoint here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-token).

Comment: Thanks and the problem was that I was using the Authorization header too which created a problem for me.